# Highcharts: how to change line color when hovering a scatterplot series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scatter-plot

I have a Highcharts scatterplot. Some details of the chart object are below:

```
plotOptions: {
scatter: {
    lineWidth:1,
    marker: {
        radius: 1,
        symbol:'circle',
        fillColor: '#800000',
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: true,
                radius:0,
                radiusPlus:2,
                lineColor: '#ff0000',
                fillColor: '#ff0000'
            }
        }
    },
    states: {
        hover: {
            halo:false,
            lineWidthPlus:2,
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the full working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/1/).
I need to change the line color when hovering the series, but I am unable to do it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with events.

All you need is to update the series color property when user hovers on a series

```
events: {
    mouseOver: function () {

        this.chart.series[this.index].update({
             color: 'red'
        });
    },
    mouseOut: function () {

        this.chart.series[this.index].update({
            color: "#b0b0b0"
        });                           
     }
 }
```

This will change the color of the series of which the point is hovered.

[here is update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/1wfotmoa/4/)

Hope This has helped you.

Comment: Am I the only one experiencing a "flickering" when hovering between the two series and having this code as well?

Comment: @HalvorStrand is sticky tracking disabled?? it is enabled by default. If you have multiple series and they run through same xAxis points, I advice to disable sticky tracking.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [strikers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1958114/strikers)

> @HalvorStrand is sticky tracking disabled?? it is enabled by default. If you have multiple series and they run through same xAxis points, I advice to disable sticky tracking. – strikers Jan 4 at 5:23

i was struggling with this until i put this after plotoptions
`series: {stickyTracking: false},`
problem solved