# console error when changing line color in a HighCharts scatterplot

Tags: debugging, events, highcharts, scatter-plot

I've adopted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575870/highcharts-how-to-change-line-color-when-hovering-a-scatterplot-series) solution to change the line color when hovering a series in a HighCharts scatterplot (JSFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/1wfotmoa/4/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                lineWidth:1,
                marker: {
                    radius: 1,
                    symbol:'circle',
                    fillColor: '#800000',
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            radius:0,
                            radiusPlus:2,
                            lineColor: '#ff0000',
                            fillColor: '#ff0000'
                        }
                    }
                },
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {

                        this.chart.series[this.index].update({
                            color: 'red'
                        });
                    },
                    mouseOut: function () {

                        this.chart.series[this.index].update({
                            color: "#b0b0b0"
                        });                           
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'A',
            color: "#b0b0b0",
            data: [[38,42],[39,39],[35,45],[35,54],{x:36,y:35,marker:{radius:8,symbol:'circle'}}
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'B',
            color: "#b0b0b0",
            data: [[46,56],[47,67],[48,69],[50,55],{x:52,y:57,marker:{radius:8,symbol:'circle'}}
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

The script works but running the web console I see that every hovering of a series causes a `TypeError: g.firePointEvent is not a function error`.

In another one of my scripts the error is `TypeError: hoverPoint.firePointEvent is not a function`.

Is this a bug of HighCharts or is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: The issue is caused by the update which is called before your action. As a result you try to refer to updated point, before end of it. The solution is use attr() method and change SVG color on path. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/53ob1pu2/. It is correct for you?

Comment: Seems working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the update which is called before your action. As a result you try to refer to updated point, before end of it. The solution is use attr() method and change SVG color on path.

```
events: {
      mouseOver: function() {

        this.chart.series[this.index].graph.attr({
            stroke: 'red'
        });
      },
      mouseOut: function() {
                    this.chart.series[this.index].graph.attr({
            stroke: '#b0b0b0'
        });
      }
    }
```

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/53ob1pu2.

Comment: Do you know which other keys/properties one can access via this.graph.attr besides stroke? Is it possible to get/set the marker properties?

Comment: Markers are separated SVG elements, so you cannot apply them by update. Summarising, your goal on mouseOver is change color and set markers?

Comment: I noticed that setting this.graph.attr is much faster than using this.update. So I wonder if I could use this.graph.attr also to change markers appearance because in my case this.update "hangs" the chart for a while.

Comment: Do you mean change symbols of markers? From what kind of marker to which one?

Comment: Same symbol, different size and color.

Comment: red dots only or other?

Comment: Does this make difference? For example, consider that the red points in the JSFiddle example have to become white circles surrounded by a thin red line.

Comment: You can manipualte it, the simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9zz37dew/. Border line is stroke, stroke-width is size of a line.

Comment: Thank you. I've made some experiments with properties x and y too.